# store data in sql server 2005 asp.net c# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a project which has internal/in built VS database... now I want       to connect it to external SQL server database

How can I do this? Does it affect my project? How about connection string that I created during my inbuilt database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pramod Niralakeri

Connect to External database using connection string.

first add the connection string to web configuration file

```
      <connectionStrings>
      <add name="managementportal" connectionString="Data Source=HSBHV;Initial Catalog=itamma00_HSB;User ID=sa;Password=HSB555" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

then  use the ConfigurationManager in cs page using connection name "managementportal"

```
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["managementportal"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to external database by specifying its name and credentials.If it is on your pc than in server give name of your PC.And if you are using sql server authentication than you have to give username and password

```
server=yourpcname;database=databasename;uid=userid;pwd=***;Pooling=false;
```

If you are using windown authentication

```
server=yourpcname;database=databasename;Pooling=false;
```

Comment: here nothing like ip & all....its a college academic project runs only in my laptop...

Comment: You said that you want to connect it to external sql server? What is external sql server ? Where it will be ?

Comment: in my lap top sql server 2005...sorry i am very new to this

Comment: so this will always run in your laptop ?

Comment: Ok in server give name of your pc like server=marajpc;

Comment: And how do you connect to it ? By windows authentication or by SQl Server Authentication ?

Comment: have used in built database in asp.net...it dint ask any authentication

Comment: Ok see my updated answer.Just replace name of your pc in server in the connection string you already created.

Answer (score 0):

Add to web.config in

configuration\connectionStrings

```
<add name="SOMECONNECTIONNAME" connectionString="server=SOMEIPORNAME;database=SOMEDATABASENAME;user id=SOMESQLUSER;password=SOMEPASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Call in code by

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOMECONNECTIONNAME"]);
            connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("StoreProcedurename", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", DBNull.Value);
                SqlDataReader DR = command.ExecuteReader();
```

etc.

Comment: what to add in web.config and how about connection strings that i create already during inbuilt database

Comment: what about connection strings used for drop down list and all?